# How to use Echarts render hierarchical data (multiple xAxis)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I am trying to use Echarts to render a bar chart with multiple xAxis in Reactjs.

I did reference someone's source code but the output does not perfectly meet my expectation
The label of second xAxis doesn't all show on the chart
https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/13839#issuecomment-1319601929

Here is a demo that I want to achieve with 3 layers of xAxis label, grateful that if you can provide me some hints / tutorial. Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you please post/link your code (current version), I don't know how your data is structured, and it would be a waste of time to start from scratch